# How to avoid memory leak for this case?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Case 1:

```
-(id)getAnObject{

        Object *someObject = [[Object alloc] init];
       //doing something

        return someObject;

}
```

Case 2:

```
-(void)dealWithAnObject{
            Object *someObject = [[Object alloc] init];
            [assignTheObjectToOther someObject];

}
```

Both Case 1 and Case 2 have some warning in XCode, what should I do to deal with these two? thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The golden rule of memory management is: everything needs to know which objects it owns. And only you can make that decision.

I highly recommend reading Apple's [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i). At least twice.

For your specific case:

1. `getAnObject` doesn't ever release the object it creates. If you're going to return it, you'll want to `autorelease` it first.
2. `dealWithAnObject` also doesn't release its object. You can either `autorelease` it or `release` it after the function call that uses it. Make sure that anything that uses it follows the same rules, and you'll be OK.